# How do i make Radio to be on the left with CSS

Tags: html, css

Im trying to replicate the
[freeCodeCamp Survey Form](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/VPaoNP)

When i use inline-block it only works only after .form-control input.

And I only want to use it for radio , but it seems like it doesn't work when I put [type="radio"] after .form-control input.

Can someone describe what is wrong? Thank you guys.

```css
form{
  background-color: grey;
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px
  
}


.form-control{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.form-control label{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
}

.form-control input, .form-control select{
 
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;  
  
}

.form-control input [type="radio"]{
  width: auto;
  display:inline-block;
 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
   <label> Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
        
      <label for="Definitely"> <input type="radio" id="Definitely" name=RadioRecommend> Definitely </label>
        
      <label for="Maybe"> <input type="radio" id="Maybe" name=RadioRecommend> Maybe </label>
        
      <label for="Not sure "> <input type="radio"  id="Not sure" name=RadioRecommend> Not sure </label>
      
          </div>
```

Comment: do you mean change the order of your `input` and `label`? your `input` comes first then your `label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose each choice into a `div` since it becomes easy to manage. Also, remove the space in `input [type="radio"]` as this selector is invalid.

```css
form {
  background-color: grey;
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px
}

.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.form-control .choice label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-control .choice input,
.form-control select {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-control .choice input[type="radio"] {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.choice{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
  <label> Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
  <div class="choice">
    <label for="Definitely"> <input type="radio" id="Definitely" name=RadioRecommend> Definitely </label></div>
  <div class="choice">
    <label for="Maybe"> <input type="radio" id="Maybe" name=RadioRecommend> Maybe </label></div>
  <div class="choice">
    <label for="Not sure "> <input type="radio"  id="Not sure" name=RadioRecommend> Not sure </label></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the whitespace between "input" and "[type="radio"]". Write as follows:

```
.form-control input[type="radio"]{
  width: auto;
  display:inline-block;  
}
```

Comment: Bro. Never have I ever felt this dumb in my whole life. Thank you man